# query to find data based on max of one field and specific value of another

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My SQL skills are minimal so I hope someone will help me. I am writing a PHP script in which I need to do some SQL queries:

I have a table called product_status, which has three 4 columns:
id
prod_id
status_date
status_code

So if we consider a product with id 1000, the table would have entries like:

```
id    prod_id   status_date            status_code  
1     1000      2015-09-01 08:20:35    100
2     1000      2015-09-01 09:22:40    200
3     1000      2015-09-01 09:35:51    300
4     1000      2015-09-01 09:42:55    400
```

Now, considering that say 300 is the status code for 'out-of-stock'. I want to write a query, where for a given date, it gives me all products that were NOT out-of-stock at the end of that day. In other words it should give me products 1000 if I query it for date '2015-09-01' since 300 is NOT the LAST entry for that product for that date in this table.

I am unable to write a query that works for this :( My query is:

```
select prod_id, status from product_status
where status_code != 300
group by prod_id, status
having date(max(status_date)) = '2015-09-01'
```

This returns me products which have statuses other than 300 as final status for the given day as well... Can anyone help correct my SQL?

Answer (score 0):

you want to filter by status, not group by it in this query, like this:

```
select prod_id, status from product_status
where status_code != 300
group by prod_id
having date(max(status_date)) = '2015-09-01'
```

Comment: @perror I am not requesting clarification, I am pointing out that it is incorrect to group by status, he wants to filter by status - that is the answer

Comment: In fact, it is more about the way you answered than the content of your answer. You should have used comments for an answer of this size. Stack-Overflow looks for detailed and insightful answers... If the question do not require more than a line, then drop a comment, not an answer. I hope you understand. :-)

Comment: While I recognize detailed answers are generally preferred, how would a question get closed in that case?  if the answer is simply a 1 line answer, I could expand, but that wouldn't provide any additional value.  -Updating my answer to include the query that I described

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT prod_id, 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(status_date ORDER BY status_date DESC), ',', 1) as max_date, 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(status_code ORDER BY status_date DESC), ',', 1) as recent_code
FROM product_status
GROUP BY prod_id
HAVING recent_code != '300' AND date(max_date) = '2015-09-01'
```

Comment: @JosephDuty You can check OP's history to see if he does post-and-forget. OP will get back after trying and will diligently thumbsup and accept answers. - OP

Comment: @UndefinedVariable fair enough - you do have a history of accepting answers - I retract my comment